# Adding a filter on MDX query

Tags: sql, mdx, olap

```
SELECT  
  {[Measures].[Imports - Tons]
   , [Measures].[Imports - Metric Tonnes]
   , [Measures].[Import Customs Value]  } ON COLUMNS,  
{CROSSJOIN (
   [Date].[Month Year].members
  ,[Country].[Country Name].members
  ,[Steel Mill Product].[Steel Mill Product Name].[Plates-Cut Length]
  ,[Concordance].[HTS 10 Digit Code].members) }
ON ROWS  
FROM [AISISteel]   
WHERE ([Date].[Year].[2014], [Concordance].[HTS 2 Digit Code].[72])
```

I have this MDX Query.
I want to get back all this data but only the data where Import-Tons>0. How would I do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can try using the `FILTER` function:

```
SELECT  
  {[Measures].[Imports - Tons]
   , [Measures].[Imports - Metric Tonnes]
   , [Measures].[Import Customs Value]  } ON COLUMNS,  
FILTER(
  {CROSSJOIN (
     [Date].[Month Year].members
    ,[Country].[Country Name].members
    ,[Steel Mill Product].[Steel Mill Product Name].[Plates-Cut Length]
    ,[Concordance].[HTS 10 Digit Code].members) }
  , [Measures].[Imports - Tons] > 0
  )
ON ROWS  
FROM [AISISteel]   
WHERE ([Date].[Year].[2014], [Concordance].[HTS 2 Digit Code].[72])
```

Also the rarely used `HAVING` clause is a possible option for you

```
SELECT  
  {[Measures].[Imports - Tons]
   , [Measures].[Imports - Metric Tonnes]
   , [Measures].[Import Customs Value]  } 
ON COLUMNS,  
  {CROSSJOIN (
     [Date].[Month Year].members
    ,[Country].[Country Name].members
    ,[Steel Mill Product].[Steel Mill Product Name].[Plates-Cut Length]
    ,[Concordance].[HTS 10 Digit Code].members) }
HAVING [Measures].[Imports - Tons] > 0
ON ROWS  
FROM [AISISteel]   
WHERE ([Date].[Year].[2014], [Concordance].[HTS 2 Digit Code].[72])
```

Also just for conciseness there is a shortcut for the `CROSSJOIN` function which is nearly always preferred:

```
SELECT  
  {[Measures].[Imports - Tons]
   , [Measures].[Imports - Metric Tonnes]
   , [Measures].[Import Customs Value]  } 
ON COLUMNS,  
    {[Date].[Month Year].members*
     [Country].[Country Name].members*
     [Steel Mill Product].[Steel Mill Product Name].[Plates-Cut Length]*
     [Concordance].[HTS 10 Digit Code].members}
HAVING [Measures].[Imports - Tons] > 0
ON ROWS  
FROM [AISISteel]   
WHERE ([Date].[Year].[2014], [Concordance].[HTS 2 Digit Code].[72])
```

---

Edit

If you compare the above to the following are the execution times much different?

```
SELECT  
  {[Measures].[Imports - Tons]
   , [Measures].[Imports - Metric Tonnes]
   , [Measures].[Import Customs Value]  } ON COLUMNS,  
  FILTER(
    NONEMPTY(
     [Date].[Month Year].members*
     [Country].[Country Name].members*
     [Steel Mill Product].[Steel Mill Product Name].[Plates-Cut Length]*
     [Concordance].[HTS 10 Digit Code].members
    ,[Measures].[Imports - Tons]
    )
  ,[Measures].[Imports - Tons] > 0
  )
ON ROWS  
FROM [AISISteel]   
WHERE ([Date].[Year].[2014], [Concordance].[HTS 2 Digit Code].[72])
```

Comment: In this example HAVING will have much much better performance

Comment: @DanielHanczyc please can you explain this comment. I know filter is generally not great in terms of performance but beyond that my knowledge of tuning mdx is limited.

Comment: Filter is applied after crossjoin operation is performed (not optmized by compiler), while 'having' clause is applied during crossjoining itself.

Comment: @George thanks - I think, either way, something this user could really benefit from is `NON EMPTY` which will be applied before `filter`/`having`

Comment: @whytheq, I totally agree about NON EMPTY, should help much